# strip html tags from data in ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, json

I have an app that has admin end on web and user end on ios. In the web end i have placed the tinymce editor that allows the admin to enter the text in paragraphs and list view. the data getting entered in database is also having html tags, In the webservice i am getting the data(that was entered from admin end) in json format but along with it i am getting html tags also.

Part of data i am getting in json format looks something like this

```
{
  "list":[{"id":"1","state_info":"<p class=\"grid-para\" style=\"box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; font-size: 1.1em; line-height: 1.7em; padding: 1em 0px 0px; font-family: \'Open Sans\', sans-serif;\" align=\"justify\">ABC...some text &amp;</p>n<p style=\"box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: \'Open Sans\', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;\"><strong style=\"box-sizing: border-box;\">ABC...some text.</strong></p>n<p style=\"box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: \'Open Sans\', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;\">ABC...some text"}]
}
```

Part of code i tried for it is

```
       @implementation NSString (stripHtml)
-(NSString*)stripHtml {
    NSString* string = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p=%@&</p=%@" withString:@""];
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<root>%@</root>", string];


    NSStringEncoding encoding = string.fastestEncoding;
    NSData* data = [string dataUsingEncoding:encoding];
    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    NSString_stripHtml_XMLParsee* parsee = [[NSString_stripHtml_XMLParsee alloc] init];
    parser.delegate = parsee;
    [parser parse];


    NSString* strippedString = [parsee getCharsFound];

    [parser release];
    [parsee release];

    return strippedString;
}
```

I have tried to use many editors but i am getting tags with almost all the editors and if i don't use any editor i get all the data as single paragraph.

Can anyone please tell how to remove these tags without removing their effect. or maybe a way with which i can enter data in paragraph and list view without tags

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
- (NSString *)stripHTML{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                            options:@{NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
                                                                                      NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                                 documentAttributes:nil
                                                                              error:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }

    return [attributedString string];

}
```

Comment: @user3732711 the method i posted here is also a category of NSString like you have. This should help remove the tags..  Replace your code with this and try.